# BIOS displays different boot options in different places

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, fedora, uefi

I recently installed Fedora on a partition on my SSD (created by the installer) and this seems to have screwed up my computer's boot options.

When I enter the UEFI boot menu, I am given two options:
[image: boot menu options]

(One is my hard drive with music etc, the other is the SSD with Windows and Fedora)

However, when I go into Configuration by hitting that button, only one hard drive appears:

[image: boot options configuration]

So I can't select the SSD with the OS on it as a default option and need to select it manually every time, otherwise my computer tries to boot off the hard drive which gives a grub rescue since there is no OS there.

Additionally I have no idea how to boot into Windows any more, as selecting the SSD from the first menu goes straight to fedora.

My motherboard is an ASRock H61M-DGS if that helps.

Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it. Sorry the pictures are bad but I can't take screenshots for this issue!

Comment: Windows may have put its boot files on the WDC drive, making it the bootable drive.

Comment: @Moab the boot files are not on the WDC drive and attempting to boot from it takes you to the grub rescue screen where i can verify that none of the disks have a /boot